# how to return IEnumerable<GenderDTO> GetGenderList()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I wanted to populate the dropdownlistfor form database but this error is arises... Can Someone help me with this to remove this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ORS.DTO.GenderDTO' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

i have to populate dropdownlist for Gender and have to get values that are stores in the database...

```
 public IEnumerable<GenderDTO> GetGenderList()
    {               
        GenderDTO model = new GenderDTO();
        var gender = from g in db.CAT_GENDER
                     select g;
        model.GenderList = new SelectList(gender, "ID", "Description");
        return model;
    }
```

GenderDTO class

```
 public class GenderDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public SelectList GenderList { get; set; }
}
```

CAT_GENDER

```
 public partial class CAT_GENDER
{
    public CAT_GENDER()
    {
        USER_PROFILE = new HashSet<USER_PROFILE>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }

    public int STATUS_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual CAT_RECORD_STATUS CAT_RECORD_STATUS { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<USER_PROFILE> USER_PROFILE { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns an `IEnumerable<GenderDTO>`:

```
public IEnumerable<GenderDTO> GetGenderList()
```

But you're trying to return a `GenderDTO`:

```
GenderDTO model = new GenderDTO();
//...
return model;
```

They're two different types.  If you want the method to return one object, change the method to do that:

```
public GenderDTO GetGenderList()
```

If, on the other hand, you want to return a collection of objects, then change your return type to do that:

```
return new List<GenderDTO> { model };
```

---

It's *highly likely* that you want the first option.  It would be kind of silly to always return a collection of exactly one object.  Though, to be fair, it's not really clear what this `GenderDTO` model is supposed to represent anyway.  You're never setting the `ID` or `Description` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `return model;` which represents a single object of type `GenderDTO`, It looks like from the question description, that you have to return a single object and not a collection. Modify your method signature and remove `IEnumerable` from return type.

But, if you have to return an `IEnumerable<GenderDTO>` then you have to create that in your code and return it like:

Something like:

```
return gender.Select(r => new GenderDTO
{
    ID = r.ID,
    Description = r.DESCRIPTION,
    GenderList = new SelectList(gender, "ID", "Description")
};
```